# Trouble styling a DIV with two background images using Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can only get the **CSS** styled image to load. The browser does not display `imgB`. The source code also only shows `imgA`. I just want to call the backgroundImage value of the Object at the time of the specific loop
My `HTML`.

```
<div onclick="displayCards()">Display Cards</div>
```

My **Javascript Objects** contain **properties** for these `DIV` **elements**. The different cards each have a unique image `imgB`. I created an **array** for the **Objects** so I can loop through them with a `for` **loop**.

```
var card_troop = { title : "troop" , type : "Unit" , image : "url(troop.png)" } ;
var card_base = { title : "base" , type : "Structure" , image : "url(base.png)" } ;
var card_wood = { title : "wood" , type : "Resource" , image : "url(wood.png)" } ;

var list = [
   card_troop ,
   card_base ,
   card_wood
   ] ;
```

The `DIV` **elements** are created by my `displayCards()` **function**, that are appended to the `body` of my `HTML` document.

```
function displayCards()
{
   card = document.createElement("div") ;
      var card_id = document.createAttribute("id") ;
      card_id.value = list[x].title ;
      card.setAttributeNode(card_id) ;
      var card_class = document.createAttribute("class") ;

         switch (list[x].type) // Card Theme Comparison
            {
            case "Unit" :
               card_class.value = "unit" ;
               break ;
            case "Structure" :
               card_class.value = "structure" ;
               break ;
            case "Resource" :
              card_class.value = "resource" ;
              break ;
            }
         card.setAttributeNode(card_class) ;

   var imgA = card.style.backgroundImage ;
   var imgB = list[x].image ;
   card.style.backgroundImage = imgA + " , " + imgB ;
}
```

Using the `switch` **Comparison**, `switch (list[x].type)`, defined by the **Object Property** `type:`, each `DIV` will have one of three **CSS** `backgroundImage` **values**.

```
div.unit { background-image:url( theme_unit.png ) ; }
div.structure { background-image:url( theme_structure.png ) ; } 
div.resource { background-image:url( theme_resource.png) ; }
```

Another **function** `builder()` calls `displayCards()` and appends the **Object** `card`.

```
function builder()
{
for ( x = 0 ; x < 9 ; x++ )
   {
   displayCards() ;
   document.body.appendChild(card) ;
   }
}
```

I believe my problem lies here. Since the `DIV` is still not appended.
To note:`imgA` is a higher index than `imgB` and has transparency to allow `imgB` to be seen.

```
   var imgA = card.style.backgroundImage ;
   var imgB = list[x].image ;
   card.style.backgroundImage = imgA + " , " + imgB ;
```

I am a minimalist coder and this is the shortest I could come up with. I do not want to have to repeat **URL's** more than once. My list of Objects is going to get much longer than three.
**NO JQUERY**

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the problem is in the line var imgA = card.style.backgroundImage ;. You should append the element first and get it's style object using window.getComputedStyle method. Link for getComputedStyle https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle. Sorry, I don;t know how to post code or link in comment

Comment: I really like this approack but I could not get it to work since the element has yet to be appended.

Comment: I have updated to reflect some details I left out.

Comment: @Anand your point makes the most sense. But how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var card_troop = { title : "troop" , type : "Unit" , image : "url(troop.png)" } ;
var card_base = { title : "base" , type : "Structure" , image : "url(base.png)" } ;
var card_wood = { title : "wood" , type : "Resource" , image : "url(wood.png)" } ;

var list = [
    card_troop,
    card_base,
    card_wood
];


function buildCard(card) {
    var elem = document.createElement('div'),
        elemCloned,
        computedBackgroundUrl,
        backgroundUrl;

    elem.id = card.title;
    elem.className = card.type.toLowerCase();


    // Clone element and temporary append to body
    elemCloned = elem.cloneNode();
    elemCloned.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(elemCloned);

    computedBackgroundUrl = window.getComputedStyle(elemCloned)['background-image'];

    if (computedBackgroundUrl) {
        var match = computedBackgroundUrl.match(/^url\((.*)\)/);
        if (match) {
            backgroundUrl = match[1];
        }
    }

    // remove element after retrieved background-image value
    elemCloned.parentNode.removeChild(elemCloned);
    elemCloned = null;

    elem.style.backgroundImage = (backgroundUrl ?  'url(' + backgroundUrl + '), ' : '') + card.image;

    computedBackgroundUrl = null;
    backgroundUrl = null;

    return elem;
}

function displayCards() {
    var body = document.body;

    for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        body.appendChild( buildCard(list[i]) );
    }

}
```

Comment: I like how minimal you reduced the code but your version does not produce two background images for one element.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly. You want to make something like this - div.unit { background-image:url( theme_unit.png ), url(troop.png) ; } ?

Comment: Sorry it did not work for me. I can't rely on the `type` property for the URL as they can get complex.

Comment: I want to call the backgroundImage value from `card`.

Comment: Sorry. You got me now really confused about what you trying to do after all. How do you want to get background-image value from a card, when the card doesn't have set background-image yet (we just created this element). Or maybe you want to get this value from background-image property assigned to a specific class (.unit, .structure etc) in your css file? Could you explain this better?

Comment: The problem is I want to get the CSS background-image value when the element has yet to be appended.

Comment: ...and because I want to use outside functions to do the appending I don't want to append first.

Comment: My problems would be easy to solve if the `displayCards()` function did the appending.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73866/discussion-between-cookieman-and-xavier).

Comment: Thanks for all your help! First clone the `card` object, then after returning the value, remove the node! What a simple solution!
Now I can call the function from an outside function and append the object from that outside function.

Answer (score 1):

Never got efficient in js but your js solution should be the js parallel.
add/remove the class on the div and swap background images according to class in css. I'm assuming this would require less js as a bonus.
hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I thought of that route but that would still require coding URL's more than once. I am trying to avoid this as my Object list is going to get much longer than three.

Comment: Plus I want the flexibility of different image combinations.

Comment: I also do not want to have to add a 
Object property to my Objects either.

Comment: I just want to call the backgroundImage value of the Object at the time of the specific loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should work through this approach. Replace "backgroundimage" and "foregroundimage" with the appropriated URLs (of course). 
Afterwards you can call the method showCard with a switch. showCard(true) shows the card's front. showCard(false) shows the card's back.

```js
var card = function(title, type, image) {
  this.title = title;
  this.type = type;
  this.image = image;
  this.background = "url('backgroundimage')";
};

card.prototype.showCard = function(turn) {
  if (turn) {
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.title));   
    ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.type));
    ele.style.backgroundImage = this.image;
    document.body.appendChild(ele);
  } else {
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.style.backgroundImage = this.background;
    document.body.appendChild(ele);
  }
};

function displayCards() {
  var card_troop = new card("TroopTitle", "TroopType", "url('foregroundimage')");
  card_troop.showCard(true);
  var card_troop_2 = new card("Troop2Title", "TroopType", "url('foregroundimage2')");
  card_troop_2.showCard(false);
};
```

```css
div {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 120px;
  border: solid;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="displayCards()" value="Display Cards" />
```

Comment: It is not to show front and back. Both images are layered over eachother. The top being transparent to reveal the lower indexed image.

Comment: What sense should that make?

Comment: The higher indexed image has a transparent window. Which is why I am using `.png`.

Comment: But why would you do that? To prevent people from downloading the 'real' image?

Comment: No, it is just for graphic reasons.

Comment: I have a custom "mask" as a transparent window which is not rectangular.

Comment: This mask also has graphic features.

Comment: I don't see any other route for my graphic goals so this subject is a mute point.

Comment: Plus I am too heavily invested into the concept graphics-wise to turn back now.

Comment: @Xavier The last comment made me laugh so hard :D We all know this feeling